# Creating Dynamic LOVs

Tags: oracle-apex, lov

I have a form in oracle apex with more than seven items on it. they are

```
SUBJECT_ID,GRADE_ID,DOMAIN_ID, CATEGORY_ID, STANDARD_CODE, STANADARD_STATEMENT, LEARNING_TARGETS.
```

I want these items `SUBJECT_ID,GRADE_ID,DOMAIN_ID, CATEGORY_ID, STANDARD_CODE` type to be select list. additionally, I want to make LOVs for each of these items.

LOV for `SUBJECT_ID`: I am making this LOV using a table `SUBJECTS` having TWO columns. MY query is `SELECT SUBJECT_ID, SUBJECT_NAME FROM SUBJECTS` It's working fine.

LOV for `GRADE_ID`: I am making this LOV using a table `GRADES` having TWO columns. MY query is `SELECT GRADE_ID, GRADE_NAME FROM GRADES` It's working fine.

LOV for `DOMAIN_ID`: I am making this LOV using a table `DOMAIN` having TRHEE columns. MY query is `SELECT DOMAIN_ID, DOMAIN_NAME FROM DOMAIN WHERE SUBJECT=:P48_SUBJECT_ID`. It's working fine.

LOV for `CATEGORY_ID`: I am making this LOV using a table `CATEGORIES` having FOUR columns. MY query is `SELECT CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME FROM CATEGORIES WHERE DOMAIN=:P4.8_DOMAIN_ID` It's working fine.

LOV for `STANDARD_CODE`: I am making this LOV using a table `CURRICULUM` having MORE THAN EIGHT columns. MY query is `SELECT CURRICULUM_ID CI, STANDARD_CODE SC FROM CURRICULUM WHERE SUBJECT=:P48_SUBJECT_ID AND GRADE_ID=:P48_GRADE_ID AND DOMAIN_ID=:P48_DOMAIN_ID AND CATEGORY_ID=:P48_CATEGORY_ID`. It's not working for me.

Kindly tell me how I can correct the 5th LOV. Thanks

Comment: "It's not working for me." is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us what the error is or why you think it is not working. Please [edit] the question and include a complete description of the issue/error.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that any of LoV queries you posted return desired result and "work fine". Their format should be:

```
select display_value,  --> you see it on the screen
       return_value    --> you don't see it; it is stored into the table
from ...
```

Code you posted suggest just the opposite, e.g.

```
SELECT SUBJECT_ID,     --> are you REALLY displaying ID to users and
       SUBJECT_NAME    --> storing NAME into the table?
FROM SUBJECTS
```

---

As of your final LoV: just as MT0 commented, we have no idea what "not working" means. You posted a whole lot of more or less useless information (queries that "work"; what should we do with them?), but said nothing about problem you have.

Therefore, I'll guess: you *forgot* to include

```
P48_SUBJECT_ID, P48_GRADE_ID, P48_DOMAIN_ID, P48_CATEGORY_ID
```

into the **Parent Item(s)** property within the "Cascading List of Values" section, e.g.

[image]

Note that query you posted presumes that all page items have a value; if any of these is NULL, query won't return anything so that would be my second guess:

```
SELECT curriculum_id ci, standard_code sc
  FROM curriculum
 WHERE     (   subject = :P48_SUBJECT_ID
            OR :P48_SUBJECT_ID IS NULL)
       AND (   grade_id = :P48_GRADE_ID
            OR :P48_GRADE_ID IS NULL)
       AND (   domain_id = :P48_DOMAIN_ID
            OR :P48_DOMAIN_ID IS NULL)
       AND (   category_id = :P48_CATEGORY_ID
            OR :P48_CATEGORY_ID IS NULL)
```

In that case, switch the "Parent required" property OFF.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments and suggestions.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions and comments. Thankfully, the problem is resolved. I was selecting the display and return values for the first four LOVs. The problem was only with the fifth one. Instead of creating LOV in the shared components, I directly wrote the SQL query on the list of values. And submitted the category_id. So it worked. Cheers